# Netbook Touchpad

Tags: laptop

I just installed Xubuntu on my Acer Aspire netbook but can not get the pointing device at all.  I am unable to access anything as a result.  Can someone please help.  Thanks.

Comment: If you have a synaptics touchpad, try installing `xf86-input-libinput`

Comment: Please all more details to the question.

Answer (score 1):

First off if your laptop has a toggle touchpad button, hit it to see if it changes things.
You may have drivers installed, but the mouse isn't activated or recognized.

Login using your keyboard/tab/ and or arrows keys.
Open a terminal using a keyboard shortcut
default is:
ctrl + alt + T

You can check this with the following commands

```
xinput
```

Find your touchpad id, it should be a 1 or 2 digit number(like 14).
Then once you have your ID, run:

```
xinput --list-props <ID>
```

This should spit out all the properties that deal with your touchpad driver.
The key thing we are looking for is something along the lines of:

```
Device Enabled (SOME_NUMBER): 0
```

Obviously 0 is off, so we want to change it with this command:

```
xinput --set-prop <ID> <THAT_NUMBER> 1
```

This should "activate" your touchpad. If this problem persists(!) you may need to change your driver ([libinput](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput) is the one I use as some features were not working with stock synaptics.)

Along with this you can create a script to fix this at startup (I personally add the commands to the end of my ~/.profile file)
The order of input devices MAY change after you logout. Because of this you can always replace the numbers in your long term solution with the String names:
IE:
xinput --set-prop 14 138 1
To
xinput set-prop 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad' 'Device Enabled' 1

Goodluck!